# ¿Como Extraer el texto de un listview personalizado?

Tags: java, android

**Hola a todos**

Mi problema actual es de como poder extraer un texto de un listview personalizado. En vez de extraer el texto extrae un valor numérico pero en String, un ejemplo el texto es chocolate y en vez de extraer chocolate extrae 0 o puede ser uno mayor. Mi punto de vista es que en vez de extraer el texto extrae la posición ¿no se si estoy en lo cierto?.

**Y porque me refiero a personalizado personalizado:** por la razón de que mi código me retornaba el valor correcto o bien en un listview con un adaptador ordinario no uno personalizado y al implementar el personalizado para mostrar imágenes me da este error.

**Mi código**

```
//Aqui almaceno el valor del texto en un String identificándolo por su posición
String listChoice = (gridview.getItemAtPosition (position)).toString();
Toast.makeText(Almacen.this, listChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Si conoce como solucionar este problema o tiene conocimiento de otra manera de poder lograr mi objetivo. Estaré encantado de escuchar sus ideas. Gracias

Comment: ListView o GridView? es importante establecer una diferencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código no muestras un `listView`,  muestras un `gridview`.

Si deseas obtener el texto de un item en un `ListView`,  se realiza de esta forma:

```
String textItemList = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

**¿Como Extraer el texto de un `listView` personalizado?**

Si deseas obtenerlo de un `ListView` personalizado, te debes referir a un layout personalizado para los elementos en el `ListView`, agrego un ejemplo en el caso de que el texto se encuentre en un TextView de este layout suponiendo un id llamado `myText`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
    //Se busca la referencia del TextView en la vista.
    TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    //Obtiene el texto dentro del TextView.
    String textItemList  = textView.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Ha perdonar no es un gridview sino un listview si no que tiene el nombre gridview porque anteriormente era un GridView

Comment: Ah ok! Si el adapter carga in layout agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Una pregunta sobre su código, su código obtiene el valor de un textview y lo almacena en un String, pero que valor almacena todo lo que aparece en el listview o solo el del Item seleccionado.Gracias.

Comment: En este caso el item seleccionado, si deseas todos los textos tendrías que realizar un loop buscando en los elementos hijo del ListView.

Comment: No deseo todos solo me dio curiosidad, ya que no note el termino position en ningún lado. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el texto de un `TextView` debes utilizar el método `getText()`

`String listChoice = (gridview.getItemAtPosition (position)).getText().toString();`

Quizas debas hacer el cast a `TextView`:

`String listChoice = ((TextView) gridview.getItemAtPosition (position))).getText().toString();`

Comment: Amigo su código tiene una falla al ejecutarse se cierra la aplicación.Gracias