# Recorrer toda las filas de un listview personalizado y obtener los valores de sus respectivos Textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una lista personalizada la cual se carga con `radiobuttons` y `textview`, al seleccionar un `radiobutton` (Sí o No) el `textview` cambia a un valor, al final de la lista tengo un botón que cuando se presione irá recorriendo fila por fila el `listview`, obteniendo los valores e imprimiendolos con un `toast`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras los elementos sean visibles pueden ser capturados con el último elemento visible, pero en mi caso tengo más de 30 filas y estas pueden variar. Quisiera capturar todo los valores de los `textview`. Como podría hacerlo?

Lo intente de la siguiente manera, pero no funciona.

```
for (int i=1; i <= lista.getCount();i++) {
    View view = lista.getChildAt(i);
    TextView x = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_respuesta);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(x),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Alguna otra forma de hacerlo.
Agradecería su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Mi `Listview` extiende de un `ArrayAdapter` y este es su código

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Preguntas> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Preguntas> datos;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.pregunta_respuesta, datos);
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;
        final PreguntasHolder holder;
        Preguntas preguntas = datos.get(position);

        if (item == null) {
            item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pregunta_respuesta, null);

            holder = new PreguntasHolder();
            holder.idPregunta = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lbl_idPregunta);
            holder.pregunta = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lbl_pregunta);
            holder.radiogroup = (RadioGroup) item.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            holder.lbl_respuesta = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lbl_respuesta);

            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[2];

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
                rb[i].setId(i);

                RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(0,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;
                params.setMargins(5,0,5,10);
                holder.radiogroup.addView(rb[i],params);
            }

            holder.radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case R.id.rbtSi:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "si", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.lbl_respuesta.setText("1");
                            break;
                        case R.id.rbtNo:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.lbl_respuesta.setText("0");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            item.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PreguntasHolder) item.getTag();
        }

        holder.idPregunta.setText(String.valueOf(preguntas.getIdPregunta()));
        holder.pregunta.setText(String.valueOf(preguntas.getPregunta()));

        return item;
    }

    public class PreguntasHolder {
        public TextView idPregunta, pregunta,lbl_respuesta;
        public RadioGroup radiogroup;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return datos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Utilizas un ArrayAdapter de base, o te creas tu uno extendiendo al mismo?

Comment: He actualizado el post incluyendo la clase donde extiendo del arrayadapter.

Comment: @MaxM existe ya una pregunta similar : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54522/como-extraer-el-texto-de-un-listview-personalizado pero en este caso deseas capturar todos los textos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y no puedes guardar el valor del radioButton (si o no) como boolean en la clase Preguntas? Y luego, en vez de recorrer tu ListView, recorres el ArrayList datos de tu ArrayAdapter.
Solo tendrías que actualizar el valor en el listener de RadioGroup

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = convertView;
    final PreguntasHolder holder;
    Preguntas preguntas = datos.get(position);

    [...]

    holder.radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rbtSi:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "si", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.lbl_respuesta.setText("1");
                    datos.get(position).setRadioGroupValue(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.rbtNo:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.lbl_respuesta.setText("0");
                    datos.get(position).setRadioGroupValue(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    [...]

}
```